# Regex.Matches problem in visual basic 2010

Tags: regex

I have this string

copiaElementos = "c'8  d'8  a8"

And when I do Regex.Matches(copiaElementos, "8.").Count() it returns 2

why is that? I don't understand, can anyone please give me a hand?

Thank you, best regards

Comment: Dot `.` matches any character, so the two matches are `8` followed by a single space.  Please review the basics of regex before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `.` mathes one character. means you are matching an 8 followed by any charactrer, and there are exactly two of those (a space is considered a character too). Because the last one has no characters after it.

if you want to count the 8s in the string you should do Regex.Matches(copiaElementos, "8").Count(). Remember every character, even a space has its own meaning in regex.

Comment: OK, thank you. So, how can I use regex to find "8." ocurrences? I need to find "8." ocurrences, not "8" ocurrences. Thanks

Comment: Escape the dot like this „8\.“

Comment: And also upvote if it helped by your question.;)

Comment: Yes, that was the solution! Thanks a lot!